# Receiving data from UART and displaying it (graphical app)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, graphics, serial-port

I was wondering if anyone know the easiest way to write an app (I would prefer VisualStudio/C#, but can be in Python or Java) to receive the data from serial port (UART) and display it (just numbers, like "counter"). The point is >>easy<< way, because I don't need anything advanced and I don't have time to do it ... but it has to be an graphical app. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say the easiest way is the use [pyserial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/), which will make it trivial to read from serial port.  As for gui, you can easily use python's built-in framework based on Tk, or use wxpython.

Comment: Any suggestion for .NET? I am much more familiar with C# than Python.

Comment: @jurij, of course you can use the SerialPort class.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx#Y0